# Decode special symbols and white-spaces in Django?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework, url-encoding

Am working with API using 
DjangoRestFramework and am registering a user.
So during registration email id "example@gmail.com" get encoded to "example%40gmail.com".
How do i decode %40 to @.I have tested this API in postman client which is hows response properly but in Rest-Client it shows this error?

example in Rest-client

**Email** : **example@gmail.com**

encoded to **example%40gmail.com**

```
How to Handle this and thanks i advance
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`urllib.unquote`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.unquote) or [`urllib.unquote_plus`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.unquote_plus):

```
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.unquote('example%40gmail.com')
'example@gmail.com'
>>> urllib.unquote('sample+example%40gmail.com')
'sample+example@gmail.com'
>>> urllib.unquote_plus('sample+example%40gmail.com')
'sample example@gmail.com'
>>>
```

Comment: What's the difference between the two methods?

Comment: `unquote_plus()` replaces the `+` with space while `unquote()` doesn't.